# Swift decoding error types inconsistency with `Bool` type

Tags: json, swift, null, decode, decodable

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "property": null
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Program<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let property: T
    
    static func decode() {
        do {
            try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: json)
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding \(T.self): \(error)\n")
        }
    }
}

Program<String>.decode()
Program<Int>.decode()
Program<[Double]>.decode()
Program<[String: Int]>.decode()
Program<Bool>.decode()
```

For every case, except for `Bool`, we get `valueNotFound`("Cannot get unkeyed decoding container -- found null value instead") error. Which is correct, according to the documentation.
Only for `Bool`, for some reason, we get `typeMismatch`("Expected to decode Bool but found null instead.") error.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same on Linux? If not, I'd think there is no particular reason for this. Someone made a mistake, and that is it.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm afraid I don't have Linux to try 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux ([fiddle](https://swiftfiddle.com/juxtssep2jdqrhvnpy3gisonim)), `[Double]` produces a `valueNotFound` and everything else produces a `typeMismatch`. This is consistent with the source of [swift-core-libs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/77af9c5a984f40e186c0ba127cff88f2a2588c15/Sources/Foundation/JSONDecoder.swift#L250), where `unkeyedContainer` (which is called when decoding the array) throws `valueNotFound` ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/77af9c5a984f40e186c0ba127cff88f2a2588c15/Sources/Foundation/JSONDecoder.swift#L250)):

```
@usableFromInline func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
    switch self.json {
    case .array(let array):
        ...
    case .null:
        throw DecodingError.valueNotFound([String: JSONValue].self, DecodingError.Context(
            codingPath: self.codingPath, 
            debugDescription: "Cannot get unkeyed decoding container -- found null value instead"
        ))
    default:
        ...
    }
}
```

whereas `typeMismatch` is thrown by the single value container created for decoding the "scalar" types ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/77af9c5a984f40e186c0ba127cff88f2a2588c15/Sources/Foundation/JSONDecoder.swift#L550C1-L556C10)).

```
func decode(_: Bool.Type) throws -> Bool {
    guard case .bool(let bool) = self.value else {
        throw self.impl.createTypeMismatchError(type: Bool.self, value: self.value)
    }

    return bool
}
```

Because of this, I'd suspect `JSONDecoder` on macOS is not purposefully implemented for `Bool` to throw `typeMismatch` and the others `valueNotFound`. It seems to use the `JSONSerialization` API to decode the JSON to an `NSDictionary` first. The behaviour of `Bool` vs the other types could be quirk of as a consequence of that.

I personally think the wording in the documentation for `typeMismatch` and `valueNotFound` are loose enough that it would be "correct" to throw either, when encountering a null value.

Comment: Interesting investigation. Nonetheless, it looks like a bug to me: `valueNotFound` should be correct in cases where a JSON null is provided and a value is expected.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I haven't been able to find a bug report about this. Feel free to submit an issue on apple/swift-core-libs-foundation (or apple/swift perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

When decoding JSON with Swift's `JSONDecoder`, if a non-optional type like `String`, `Int`, `[Double]`, or `[String: Int]` encounters a null value, it throws a valueNotFound error because it can't decode null into a non-optional type.

However, for `Bool`, which can only be true or false, encountering null throws a typeMismatch error *because null isn't considered a valid boolean value*.

To handle this, you can make your property type optional if you expect null values in your JSON.

```
struct Program<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let property: T?
    
    static func decode() {
        do {
            try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: json)
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding \(T.self): \(error)\n")
        }
    }
}
```